# Wait for button press in foreach

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF application that needs to show the user the name of an object in an XML file, wait for them to read it, then allow them to press a Continue button and see the next one.

I've simplified the code below, but need a way to wait for the button press.

```
private void Waitforpress()
{ 
    XDocument puppies = XDocument.Load(@"C:\puppies.xml");

    foreach (var item in puppies.Descendants("Row")
    {
        PuppyName = item.Element("puppyName").Value;

        // Call Print PuppyName function

        // WAIT HERE FOR BUTTON PRESS BEFORE GOING TO NEXT PUPPY NAME
    }        
}
```

Comment: Idea would be to Load the xml contents and on button click store the last element you read. Based on that read the next element on next click.
Idea is to store the current index or anything to iterate over the elements. and use button click to iterate.

Comment: Store the name in a List<T> then show them on button press by changing List index.

Comment: You've got this back to front.  WPF runs an event loop, user actions are events that you listen and react to.  You can't sit and poll for a button press.

Comment: Well, you /can/... but don't.

Comment: @Bradley I was about to say the exact same thing. You beat me to it.

Answer (score 3):

You should not really load the file inside the button like that, I would suggest you to create a procedure that reads the file into a queue and, when the user press the button, you read the next queued item and show it to the user, such as:

```
    Queue<XElement> puppiesQueue = new Queue<XElement>();

    void LoadPuppies()
    {
        XDocument puppies = XDocument.Load(@"C:\puppies.xml");
        foreach (XElement puppie in puppies.Descendants("Row"))
            puppiesQueue.Enqueue(puppie);
    }

    void Button_Click()
    {
        //Each time you click the button, it will return you the next puppie in the queue.
        PuppyName = puppiesQueue.Dequeue().Element("puppyName").Value;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following method to create a `Task` that will be completed when the button is clicked:

```
public static Task WhenClicked(this Button button)
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
    RoutedEventHandler handler = null;
    handler = (s, e) =>
    {
        tcs.TrySetResult(true);
        button.Click -= handler;
    };
    button.Click += handler;
    return tcs.Task;
}
```

You can then `await` that task so that your method will continue executing after the button is clicked:

```
private async Task Waitforpress()
{ 
    XDocument puppies = XDocument.Load(@"C:\puppies.xml");

    foreach (var item in puppies.Descendants("Row")
    {
        PuppyName = item.Element("puppyName").Value;

        // Call Print PuppyName function

        await button.WhenClicked();
    }        
}
```

Note that you probably want to be doing the file IO asynchronously, not synchronously, so as to not block the UI thread.